# Some issues with Anonsurf and Tor on 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, tor

Like i said on the title i have some issues with Anon and Tor.
I have installed Anonsurf from the famous github release, once installed if i try to launch Tor, it doen't start.

if i stop anonsurf then tor window pop-up and connect to the tor-network.

Someone have experienced the same issues ?

On parrotOS Anonsurf and Tor work flawlessy toghether. Why isn't the same on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2):

I have ported [ParrotSec/anonsurf](https://github.com/ParrotSec/anonsurf) to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. You can download the ported version here [moonchitta/anonsurf-ubuntu](https://github.com/moonchitta/anonsurf-ubuntu).
Clone it with

```
git clone https://github.com/moonchitta/anonsurf-ubuntu.git
```

Make sure you have tor installed, if not then install it with

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

After installing tor, cd into the directory and execute

```
sudo make install
```

and then run it like

```
sudo anonsurf start
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: it's possible run your anonsurf porting as system service? Could you explain how? Thanks!

Comment: Yes its possible, anonsurf is just a script, that starts tor and changes some iptables rule. create a systemd service script, and add ExecStart and ExecStop path to anonsurf.sh start and stop call.