# Trying to route proxy connection through squid and then anonsurf

Tags: tor, squid, squid-deb-proxy

I am trying to route my proxy connection from squid through anonsurf on  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS . It does not work when I enable anonsurf anymore. (I have squid and anonsurf both running on my Ubuntu 18.04 server)

I followed these tutorials -

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-squid-proxy-on-ubuntu-20-04

[Some issues with Anonsurf and Tor on 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160092/some-issues-with-anonsurf-and-tor-on-18-04-lts)

The proxy server does not let me connect my windows computer to my server and back to the internet once I turn on anonsurf.

Any ideas how to fix this?